# Remove duplicates from json array in a json file

Tags: python, arrays, json, scrapy

I have a very large json file with thousands of rows that look like this (scraped):

```
[
{"result": ["/results/1138/dundalk-aw/2022-03-11/806744", "/results/1138/dundalk-aw/2022-03-11/806745", "/results/1138/dundalk-aw/2022-03-11/806746", "/results/1138/dundalk-aw/2022-03-11/806747", "/results/1138/dundalk-aw/2022-03-11/806748", "/results/1138/dundalk-aw/2022-03-11/806749", "/results/1138/dundalk-aw/2022-03-11/806750", "/results/1138/dundalk-aw/2022-03-11/806751", "/results/14/exeter/2022-03-11/804190", "/results/14/exeter/2022-03-11/804193", "/results/14/exeter/2022-03-11/804194", "/results/14/exeter/2022-03-11/804192", "/results/14/exeter/2022-03-11/804196", "/results/14/exeter/2022-03-11/804191", "/results/14/exeter/2022-03-11/804195", "/results/30/leicester/2022-03-11/804201", "/results/30/leicester/2022-03-11/804200", "/results/30/leicester/2022-03-11/804198", "/results/30/leicester/2022-03-11/804197", "/results/30/leicester/2022-03-11/804199", "/results/30/leicester/2022-03-11/804202", "/results/37/newcastle/2022-03-11/804181", "/results/37/newcastle/2022-03-11/804179", "/results/37/newcastle/2022-03-11/804182", "/results/37/newcastle/2022-03-11/804180", "/results/37/newcastle/2022-03-11/804177", "/results/37/newcastle/2022-03-11/804176", "/results/37/newcastle/2022-03-11/804178", "/results/513/wolverhampton-aw/2022-03-11/804352", "/results/513/wolverhampton-aw/2022-03-11/804353", "/results/513/wolverhampton-aw/2022-03-11/806925", "/results/513/wolverhampton-aw/2022-03-11/804350", "/results/513/wolverhampton-aw/2022-03-11/804354", "/results/513/wolverhampton-aw/2022-03-11/804349", "/results/513/wolverhampton-aw/2022-03-11/804351", "/results/1303/al-ain/2022-03-11/806926", "/results/1244/goulburn/2022-03-11/807045", "/results/869/sakhir/2022-03-11/806948", "/results/1244/goulburn/2022-03-11/807045", "/results/869/sakhir/2022-03-11/806948"]},
{"result": ["/results/8/carlisle/2022-03-10/804174", "/results/8/carlisle/2022-03-10/804172", "/results/8/carlisle/2022-03-10/804170", "/results/8/carlisle/2022-03-10/804175", "/results/8/carlisle/2022-03-10/804171", "/results/8/carlisle/2022-03-10/804173", "/results/8/carlisle/2022-03-10/805620", "/results/1353/newcastle-aw/2022-03-10/804340", "/results/1353/newcastle-aw/2022-03-10/804341", "/results/1353/newcastle-aw/2022-03-10/804338", "/results/1353/newcastle-aw/2022-03-10/804342", "/results/1353/newcastle-aw/2022-03-10/804337", "/results/1353/newcastle-aw/2022-03-10/804339", "/results/394/southwell-aw/2022-03-10/804346", "/results/394/southwell-aw/2022-03-10/804344", "/results/394/southwell-aw/2022-03-10/804345", "/results/394/southwell-aw/2022-03-10/804348", "/results/394/southwell-aw/2022-03-10/806779", "/results/394/southwell-aw/2022-03-10/804343", "/results/394/southwell-aw/2022-03-10/804347", "/results/394/southwell-aw/2022-03-10/806778", "/results/198/thurles/2022-03-10/806623", "/results/198/thurles/2022-03-10/806624", "/results/198/thurles/2022-03-10/806625", "/results/198/thurles/2022-03-10/806626", "/results/198/thurles/2022-03-10/806627", "/results/198/thurles/2022-03-10/806628", "/results/198/thurles/2022-03-10/806629", "/results/90/wincanton/2022-03-10/804183", "/results/90/wincanton/2022-03-10/804186", "/results/90/wincanton/2022-03-10/804188", "/results/90/wincanton/2022-03-10/804185", "/results/90/wincanton/2022-03-10/804187", "/results/90/wincanton/2022-03-10/804184", "/results/90/wincanton/2022-03-10/804189", "/results/219/saint-cloud/2022-03-10/807032", "/results/219/saint-cloud/2022-03-10/806812", "/results/219/saint-cloud/2022-03-10/806837", "/results/219/saint-cloud/2022-03-10/807033", "/results/219/saint-cloud/2022-03-10/807037", "/results/219/saint-cloud/2022-03-10/807041", "/results/219/saint-cloud/2022-03-10/807042", "/results/219/saint-cloud/2022-03-10/807043", "/results/219/saint-cloud/2022-03-10/807044", "/results/219/saint-cloud/2022-03-10/806837", "/results/219/saint-cloud/2022-03-10/807033"]}
]
```

Now, inside the "result" arrays there are some duplicates. In this case for example **/results/1244/goulburn/2022-03-11/807045**

How could I filter these duplicates out?
I found some solutions here on Stackoverflow to check for duplicate "result" arrays, but not for checking if anything inside the array is a duplicate. At least nothing I tried worked, but I guess I am messing something up.
Tried for two days, but could not make out this one on my own - or I am too stupid to find the answer in the smiliar questions here on stackoverflow - and I have very very limited Java knowledge.

I looked into converting the json into a list and then filtering out the duplicates, but that seemed way to clunky for a large file?

Comment: How about convert each list into a set and back to list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have all the JSON data loaded you can `map` the results, remove the duplicated ones with `set` and convert back to `list` to preserve the original structure:

```
data = [{...}]  # large JSON data list
data = list(map(lambda x: {'result': list(set(x['result']))}, data))
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, no I can convert it back to a json file and use this - and look into the things I did not get, like the set() and lambda - Time to learn some more :)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily just use a `set` data type in python and you can use a loop that goes inside the Dict file and goes one by one and appending(using the update()) it to a set variable, sadly I'm too lazy to write the code that will solve your problem but you can read more on sets and write your code(
[W3-School](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp)
[How to append to a set](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/append-values-to-a-set-in-python/#:%7E:text=The%20update()%20method%20can,and%20arrays%20to%20the%20set.))

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that as well. Goal is to not ask here, but find it out by myself. Have been to W3 often, but kind of missed how to use set() properly!